# Preventing Anti virus conflicts

Tags: virus, anti-virus

I have HitmanPro, Anti-malwareBytes, and ESET installed on the computer.  Is there a way to disable the real time functions of one or more of these to prevent conflicts and improve performance?  Hitman does not seem to run all the time, rather periodically, on its own sked.  AMB claims to be watching all the time, though I do not get alerts, and find pups and some actually malware during formal scans.  ESET is all on-all the time.  But it too seldom issues warnings.  The computer is associated with a criminal law practice, and hence is FULL of sensitive info.  Who what when where how why.  Can I dispense with some or most of these?  It seems to get "the slows" and occasionally freeze.  No data losses noted, though.

Comment: Why so many? By AMB do you mean MBAM? I would just stick to that one if you have the real-time protection. If not, I just use MBAM+MSE.

Answer (score 3):

Running multiple Anti-Virus programs isn't recommended because of those conflicts. One AV product might think that another AV is malware because it is checking/accessing your files at this very moment. This can lead to misbehaving AV products and false alerts aswell as not recognized viruses. HitmanPro should be fine to use besides one installed AV product but running two AV products with real-time scans is a bad idea in general.

Comment: Thanks, BenjaminS for the prompt reply:
I guess my question was really a call for an evaluation of the relative merits of the AV/AM programs.  I know and accept that I will have to get rid of at least one, maybe two of the three.  I just want to know which is the most efficacious of the three in stopping incoming threats.  None seems impregnable, and none does a very good (perceptible) job of warning me that there is trouble ahead.  Ideas?   Is MS EMET a good idea/apt to lead to further conflicts?

Comment: Generally speaking, ESET recognizes most viruses quite quickly and efficiently. But I agree with MC10 that antimalwarebytes is also a good product to use. A possible cause for no warnings could be the program settings of each AV product. They are often used in an "auto-pilot" mode which automatically chooses what to do with found malware. No product can protect you against everything but there are tests which show that a handfull of products do a good job against most dangers. Read here for more: http://www.av-comparatives.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/avc_prot_2015a_en.pdf